# Error: Could not find or load main class Inteiros Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javaLoiane/aula11/Inteiros (wrong name: Inteiros)

Tags: java

Quando vou compilar com o javac, funciona normalmente mas quando vou tentar executar o codigo compilado ex:"java Inteiros" aparece isto:
Error: Could not find or load main class Inteiros
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javaLoiane/aula11/Inteiros (wrong name: Inteiros)
OBS: Quando vou tentar executar diretamente sem compilar ex:"java Inteiros.java" o codigo tambem funciona normalmente, e este erro esta acontecendo tambem no code runner do VScode mas nao acontece se rodar com propria extencao de Java do VScode

```
package javaLoiane.aula11;

public class Inteiros {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final byte idade01 = 20;

        final short idade02 = 21;

        final int idade03 = 22;

        final long idade04 = 23;
        
        System.out.println("Valor variavel idade01 = " + idade01);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você poderia mostrar os comandos que está usando na linha de comando? Pode ser que esteja executando o comando na pasta errada e isso causa um problema para achar o pacote correto.

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde! Não há nenhum problema com o código em si. Porém como a classe Inteiros está no pacote javaLoiane.aula11, o comando de execução deve ser realizado no diretório base onde está localizado o pacote(pasta) **javaLoiane**, e referir à classe por seu nome completo **javaLoiane.aula11.Inteiros**.

Realizei um teste criando este pacote na área de trabalho e compilei da seguinte forma:

```
javac -cp C:\Users\mprado\Desktop javaLoiane\aula11\Inteiros.java
```

E executei a classe compilada:

```
java javaLoiane.aula11.Inteiros
```

Segue imagem com os comandos acima executados e a saída:
[image: execução do código]

Espero que resolva o problema!